# Combined model validation summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

this is my first question on stackoverflow, so please be kind if I should be missing something.
I have two forms, each linked to its own action (for data modification) combined in a single view. Currently, I am using partials and a parent model which consists of the two models assigned to the forms.

My main view looks a bit like this:

```
@model ReportingUploadPortal.Models.ManageUserDataModel
@Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial", Model.PasswordModel)
@Html.Partial("_ChangeEMailPartial",Model.EmailModel)
```

My parent model is this:

```
public class ManageUserDataModel
{
    public ChangeEmailModel EmailModel { get; set; }
    public LocalPasswordModel PasswordModel { get; set; }
}
```

I get the validation summary information displayed two times, for each of my two partial views (they are very similar). It seems the validation information is tied to the parent model, not to each of the two child models.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeEmail", "Account")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Change your email</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EMail)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EMail)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEMail)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmEMail)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Change email" />
</fieldset>
```

}

How can I get a seperate validation summary for each form/model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Html.ValidationSummary()` is just that a summary. It is actually a list of errors which is on the model. So I believe that each model should have it's own summary (not certain about this).

I believe that you are getting duplicate summaries because you have this line: `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in each form in each partial view. Every time you have this line it will print out the whole summary to the page. You can change the granularity of the summaray with some flags, but there are also alternatives to using the whole summary e.g. `@Html.ValidationMessage()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey DubstepCat, thanks for your hints. I need a summary of all validation errors per model in my szenario. I will have a look at ValidationMessage and try to find out about those flags you mentioned. Any further help/hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The flags and the ValidationMessage are not what I am looking for, sadly. Does anybody have another idea how to solve this?

Comment: I solved this meanwhile, by adding the summary to the main view. DubstepCat's hints helped me, so I will accept his answer.